# Same Nginx FastCGI Cache Conf, works on previous sites but not this one

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

I applied the same nginx fastcgi cache configuration to a website I am currently working on, it failed, but it works fine on my previous sites.

Always miss, when log in is bypass.

All sites are wordpress + woocommerce

Current site's nginx version is 1.12.2, others are 1.10.2

Here is the configuration:

```
fastcgi_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=WordPress:500m inactive=360m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500;
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie X-Accel-Expires X-Accel-Redirect;
server{
    ......#other codes

    add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

    ......#other codes

    #Cache everything by default
    set $no_cache 0;

    #Don't cache POST requests
    if ($request_method = POST)
    {
        set $no_cache 1;
    }

    #Don't cache if the URL contains a query string
    if ($query_string != "")
    {
        set $no_cache 1;
    }

    #Don't cache the following URLs
    if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|/cart/|index.php|/my-account/|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
        set $no_cache 1;
    }

    if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
        set $no_cache 1;
    }

    #Don't cache if there is a cookie called PHPSESSID
    if ($http_cookie = "PHPSESSID")
    {
        set $no_cache 1;
    }

    if ($http_cookie ~* "(wordpress_logged_in_|wp\-postpass_|woocommerce_items_in_cart|woocommerce_cart_hash)")
    {
        set $no_cache 1;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
        fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;
        fastcgi_cache WordPress;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 360m;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After days of trial and error, I spot one tiny dot, the dot behind permissions, like this: drwxr-x---.

I search about it, turned out it is selinux related. My current site has the selinux installed and enabled, its policy to nginx causes the nginx fastcgi cache not working.

So the solution is to make nginx fastcgi cache location to comply with selinux policy (httpd_t).